High CPU usage. What seems to be the problem and what can be the fix?
I am running Ubuntu 22.04 on an 8GB laptop. The mentioned process in the picture is consuming 70.4% CPU even when my laptop is idling. Upon brief research, I got to know that this much CPU usage is unusually high for an ACPI process. Can someone explain what the problem is?


There are others who experience this issue. Your best option would be a BIOS/UEFI update.

What kernel are you using? Try a different (previous) one. also see https://forum.manjaro.org/t/irq-9-acpi-process-using-27-cpu/162380 & https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/776886/irq-9-acpi-process-using-27-cpu @ https://www.rigacci.org/wiki/doku.php/doc/appunti/linux/sa/irq_acpi_apic

@ArturMeinild if I follow the solution you mentioned, what  downside am I looking at?

None I believe..

@ArturMeinild alright Imma try this
